# Download the whole html page content using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> I need to download the whole content of html pages `images , css , js`.

---

**First Option**:

- Download the page by `urllib` or `requests`,
- Extract the page info. by `beutiful soup` or `lxml`,
- Download all links and
- Edit the links in original page torelative.

**Disadvantages**

- multiple steps.
- The downloaded page will never be identical to remote page. `may be due to js or ajax content`

---

**Second option**

Some authors recommend automating the webbrowser to download the page; so the java scrip and ajax will executed before download.

[scraping ajax sites and java script](http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/)

I want to use this option.

---

**First attempt**

So I have copied this piece of `selenium` code to do 2 steps:

- Open the URL in firefox browser
- Download the page.

---

**The code**

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False )
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.environ["HOME"])
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False )
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/html,text/webviewhtml,text/x-server-parsed-html,text/plaintext,application/octet-stream');

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

def open_new_tab(url):
    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t").perform()
    browser.get(url)
    return browser.current_window_handle

# call the function
open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
# Result: the browser is opened t the given url, no download occur
```

---

**Result**

unfortunately no download occurs, it just opens the browser at the `url` provided (first step).

---

**Second attempt**

I think in downloading the page by separate function; so I have added this function.

**The function added**

```
def save_current_page():      
    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "s").perform()

# call the function
open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
save_current_page()
```

---

**Result**

```
# No more; the browser is opened at the given url, no download occurs.
```

---

**Question**
How to automate downloading webpages by selenium ??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Extract the page source?  Selenium is doing exactly what it's supposed to do:  Open a web page for user interaction.

Comment: I want to download the webpage by the default browser downloader. I know that I can download the page by 2 steps : 1/extract the source by `selenium` or anyway 2/ write the source to local file. but I need to avoid this method. I need to simulate the normal user, to download the whole page content once (images , css , js)

Comment: Have you tried with requests? It can get all the info on webpage.

Comment: `requests` module requires many steps, 1/downloading the page, 2/extracting all links by `lxml` or `beutifulsoup`, 3/downloading the extracted link, 4/editing the links in the original page to relative ... plus the problem in extracting java script and ajax. you can try `requests` module in downloading [www.google.com] . the downloaded page will be tottaly different than the real page; despite you successfully extract all info.